# Is there a standard library class for substrings?

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a big read-only string that I scan for syntax and based on that simple syntax I extract a bunch of smaller strings that I use later for further processing. Based on testing, creating and copying most of the big string into the small strings is kind of a performance bottleneck (there are thousands of them per each big string).

I figured that I don't actually need to allocate for-, and copy the data though. What I really need is a sort of string snippet type instead that would only store a pointer to the start of the relevant data and the length but at the same time, it should be a drop-in replacement for std::string and all the standard library interactions it has.

That would be the easiest to implement anyways, I could roll my own class for that and implement the functions I need but if there is already something like it in the standard library then why bother.

So basically, is there a substring sort of class in STL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, since C++17 you have [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view).

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

int main() {
    std::string foo = "Hello world";

    std::string_view a(foo.c_str(), 5);
    std::string_view b(foo.c_str() + 6, 5);

    std::cout << a << '\n'   // prints Hello
              << b << '\n';  // prints world
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is where using `std::string_view` instead of `std::string` is very beneficial in reducing copies of those original strings and being able to use [`std::string_view::substr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/substr).

Instead of copying the strings you are operating on, a string view provides a *view* to the underlying string - pretty much just the pointer to the start of the string and the size of it.